What is tangential and radial velocity of light in Schwarzschild metric at distance $r$ for observer that is infinitely far away?
What i have learned from Schwarzschild metric is that the time dilation at
radius $r$ compared to distant observers time is:
$$ \frac{\tau_r }{t_\infty } = \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}} $$
and i have heard that there is also radial length contraction for some small length $$ \Delta l_r $$ if it is compared to small length at infinity $$ \Delta l_\infty,r $$ :
$$ \frac{\Delta l_r }{\Delta l_\infty } = \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}} $$
I also know that for local observer at distance r, the local velocity of light is always c in all directions.
Using these three facts i noticed that can deduce the velocity of light in radial and tangential direction at radius r compared to local velocity of light for observer that is infinitely far away (in his perspective):
velocity of light in radial direction:
$$  \frac{c_{rad,r}}{c_{\infty} } = (1-\frac{r_s}{r}) $$
velocity of light in tangential direction:
$$ \frac{c_{tan,r}}{c_{\infty} } = \sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}} $$
And i can now easily compare velocities of light in either radial or tangential direction between two different places:
$$ \frac{c_{rad,r_1}}{c_{rad,r_2} } = \frac{(1-\frac{r_s}{r_1})}{(1-\frac{r_s}{r_2})} $$
$$ \frac{c_{tan,r_1}}{c_{tan,r_2} } = \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{r_s}{r_1}}{1-\frac{r_s}{r_2}}} $$
Is this right?

That's correct, see here at "The local velocity" and "The shapiro-delayed velocity"

Perhaps it is also worth mentioning that the tangential and radial coordinate speeds of light are both zero at the horizon.
